# How can I add/remove an owner to gnosis-safe wallet from solidity smart contract?

Tags: solidity, gnosis-safe, gnosis

I was searching through docs and youtube guides but couldn't find an answer -  I have a multisigwallet in rinkeby network. How can I add/remove an owner from solidity smart contract?

More info:
I have a voting smart-contract which is getting weight as balanseOf(voter). So if weight of voter is more than some value - they can add owners to MultiSigWallet. There I need to call somehow add-owner function from gnosis-safe.

there was a function addOwnerWithThreshold(address owner, uint256 _threshold) but I kinda not get it - if I just import 'https://github.com/gnosis/safe-contracts/blob/main/contracts/GnosisSafe.sol' to my .sol contract and call addOwnerWithThreshold from my contract - it's not deploying

so how can I call/use this add-owner thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`addOwnerThreshold` is a protected function. Check `authorized` modifier in the function definition. It can be called only by the Safe itself. If any contract could simply call this function, it would be nothing but a security flaw.

What you can do is to call `execTransaction` with all necessary signatures and encoded transaction data for `addOwnerThreshold`.

OR

you can create a module contract, modules can be used to extend the Safe functionality, and they can execute transactions from the Safe:
https://docs.gnosis-safe.io/contracts/modules-1
https://gist.github.com/rmeissner/c66371a4b030109cde1020f427122462

Comment: How can I test it now? With module contract. Any examples?
I tried like this https://gist.github.com/rmeissner/208e35db13d0ebf53b6e35838f1c8122 example
but I have an error for not-initialized RecoveryKeyModule  when I'm testing this